# Socket.io and testing with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mocha.js, chai

I am using Mocha and chai for client testing of a small app that I wrote. However, I have run into a problem where even though I **know** my socket is connected, mocha reports that it isn't. I have looked around and can't seem to find something that satisfies my needs. Here is the code that I am using for testing.

```
var assert = chai.assert;

describe('index', function(){
    var socket = rpsApp.setupSocket();
    it('should be connected', function(){
        assert.equal(true, socket.socket.connected);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `rpsApp.setupSocket()`? How do you know that the socket is connected?

Comment: Its just socket = io.connect('localhost') + some event setup. I know its connected because the terminal displays the connection info.

Answer (score 1):

```
var chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
var io = require('socket.io-client');

describe("Socket-Server", function () {
  it('user connected and able to send msg through socket.', function (done) {
    var client = io(socketURL);
    client.on('connect', function (data) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

update the socketURL

Answer (score 0):

You need [socket.io-***client***](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) library.